# Unable to display the results from my returned array using axios and vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have tried to follow the guidance I have already received but I am encountering the following issue:

I have no errors in the console or terminal, but nothing is displayed even when I know I have an array of data.

My updated code is as follows, I am sure I have followed the guidance kindly provided.

HTML:

```
<tr v-if="myuser" v-for="myuser in allMyUsers" :key="">
  <td>{{ myuser.email }}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {

    computed: {

      allMyUsers () {
        return !this.$store.getters.myuser ? false : this.$store.getters.myuser
      },
    },
    created () {
      this.$store.dispatch('allMyUsers')
    }
  }
</script>

GETTER:

myuser (state) {
  return state.myuser
},
```

Function:

```
allMyUsers ({commit, state}) {
     if (!state.idToken) {
       return
     }
        globalAxios.get('/users.json' + '?auth=' + state.idToken)
          .then(res => {
            const data = res.data
            const myusers = []
            for (let key in data) {
              const myuser = data[key]
              myuser.id = key
              myusers.push(myuser)
           }

        commit('storemyuser', myusers)
      })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

And finally my MUTATION:

```
storemyuser (state, myuser) {
  state.myuser = myuser
},
```

Thank you again for your assistance, you guys really are great at helping newbies like me learn.

I should add that I know from the console my function is returning the data I expect

Comment: Let me see the definition of your store

Comment: Remove `v-if="myuser"` from your code. It may work

Comment: In your component
`allMyUsers () {
        return !this.$store.getters.myuser ? [] : this.$store.getters.myuser
      }`
It should be an empty array `[]` by default.

Comment: Thanks for the replys, removing the v-if didnt work and adding the [] generates an error unexpected token